# How do I get values of certain row by column names?

Tags: command-line, scripts

This is the output for the command `aws iam get-credential-report --query 'Content' --output text | base64 -d` from this output how to grep the values of `access_key_1_active` and `access_key_1_last_rotated` of user username `mahi-user`?

```
user,arn,user_creation_time,password_enabled,password_last_used,password_last_changed,password_next_rotation,mfa_active,access_key_1_active,access_key_1_last_rotated,access_key_1_last_used_date,access_key_1_last_used_region,access_key_1_last_used_service,access_key_2_active,access_key_2_last_rotated,access_key_2_last_used_date,access_key_2_last_used_region,access_key_2_last_used_service,cert_1_active,cert_1_last_rotated,cert_2_active,cert_2_last_rotated
<root_account>,arn:aws:iam::929815623526:root,2020-04-13T07:32:24+00:00,not_supported,2020-07-24T04:03:37+00:00,not_supported,not_supported,false,true,2020-07-17T05:20:25+00:00,N/A,N/A,N/A,true,2020-06-26T10:12:43+00:00,2020-07-24T06:20:00+00:00,us-east-1,s3,false,N/A,false,N/A
mahi-user,arn:aws:iam::929815623526:user/mahi-user,2020-07-21T06:21:51+00:00,true,no_information,2020-07-21T06:21:53+00:00,N/A,false,true,2020-07-21T06:21:53+00:00,N/A,N/A,N/A,false,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,false,N/A,false,N/A
```

Comment: Doesn't `aws iam get-credential-report` natively produce JSON? if so, please consider using a proper JSON parser such as `jq` rather than a text-based tool to extract values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` in the following way ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/how-to-print-certain-columns-by-name)):

**1st** create `awk` script as this:

```bsh
$ cat usr-col.awk
```

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        ix[$i] = i
    }
}
NR>1 {
    if ( $1 ~ usr ) print $ix[c1], $ix[c2]
}
```

where:

- `FS = ","` will set the field separator to `,`;
- `NR==1` means if it is the first row of the table;
- the `for` loop will create associative array: `ix[column name] = <column number>`;
- `NR>1` means any row of the table which number is bigger than `1`;
- `if ( $1 ~ usr )` will provide output if the first field of a line match to the value of the variable `usr` (the value could be regex);
- `print $ix[c1]` will output the value of the field mummer equal to the column name provided by the value of the variable `c1`...

**2nd** use the script in this way:

```bsh
aws ... | awk -f usr-col.awk usr='mahi-user' c1='access_key_1_active' c2='access_key_1_last_rotated'
```

---

I do not have the `aws` command, so in order to perform a test I've stored the provided output in a file, also I've added few lines with data for other users. Here is one of the tests I made - it searches data for multiple users (`mahi-user` and `spas`) within two arbitrary columns (`arn` and `password_enabled`):

```bsh
$ cat aws.output | awk -f usr-col.awk usr='mahi-user|spas' c1='arn' c2='password_enabled'
arn:aws:iam::929815623526:user/mahi-user true
arn:aws:iam::929815623526:user/spas false
```

Comment: But I cant see any output while running the above method

Comment: Hi, @allada01, according to the output you've provided within the question the method works. Please use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and paste the raw output of your `aws` command - I would tray to do an another test.